# Return bool value from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, httpresponse

I am using Web Api 2 to create 1 user. Below is code

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUserData(User user)
{                            
    try
    {
        //Code
        .
        .
        user.Update();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "error");
    }
}
```

I trying to call this method from code behind like

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:65486/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Stock/UpdateUserData", userObject).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string final = result.Result;
        }  
    }
    else
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Now I have few queries

- Can we return Boolean value true/false in HttpResponseMessage. I mean
  in CreateErrorResponse .
- What is best way to check if user get updated or not ?
- Can this code be improved?

Answer (score 5):

**1) Can we return Boolean value true/false in HttpResponseMessage. I mean in CreateErrorResponse?**

Technically you have following options

a) CreateErrorResponse will create HttpError object.

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, false.ToString());
```

Serialized response will be

```
 {"Message":"False"}
```

b) Or you can

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, false.ToString());
```

Response will be

```
"False"
```

**2) What is best way to check if user get updated or not ?
3) Can this code be improved?**

In my opinion, it is best to align your api with REST recommendation
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

Generally REST post api returns the resource created. Ex-

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUserData(User user)
{                            
    try
    {
        // Validate user 
        // if invalid request return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, validationErrorMessage);

        //Code to change user
        user.Update();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "error");
    }
}
```

If response is anything except 201, that means error creating user. Error details should be in message.